# Using contains and match at same time?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a simple way to do this type of compare:

```
$s =  {"This is a dog" ,"This is a cat"}

$s | where {$_.Phrase -contains -match{"dog",cat","rat"} }
```

Basically, if the left contains any part of anything on the right, I want it returned.

Or do I have to do -or for each thing on the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `$s` is an array of strings (and not a scriptblock) you could create the appropriate regular expression for the `-match` operator and just use that:

```
# ~> $s =  @("This is a dog" ,"This is a cat", "this is neither")

# ~> $s | where {$_ -match "dog|cat|rat" }
This is a dog
This is a cat
```